# Angular frontend is not able the fetch the API(.Net)

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I have created an admin panel on Angular (frontend), .Net Core (backend) and SQL. I am facing an issue calling the API on my hosting server, while on local device its working fine. In my server I have example.com where I have hosted the angular file which is working fine and inside example.com I created the folder "API" were the .net API's are hosted.
I tried changing the URL in .net folder and angular as well.

.Net

launchSetting.json

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61970",
      "sslPort": 44311
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "DwarikaAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://example.com/API",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using API.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: "mainOrigins",
    policy =>
    {            policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

var app = builder.Build();    
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}    
app.UseHttpsRedirection();    
app.UseCors("mainOrigins");    
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
app.Run();
```

Angular

Environment.ts

```
export const environment={
    production: false,
    apiUrl:"https://example.com/API/api" //"api" is my controller route path
}
```

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../models/hero';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  private url="Hero";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient ) { }
  public getHero(): Observable<Hero[]>{
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}`);
  }
}
```

Please let me know where I am going worng

Comment: Whats the error you are receiving in client-side console?

Comment: I getting this error on console 
GET https://example.com/API/api/Hero 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This means that your Backend API crashes without providing the data. I would suggest you put a breakpoint in the Backend endpoint and debug from there onwards

Comment: Thank you!
I would really appreciate it if you could share some references. as I am new to .Net

Comment: first try call your api endpoint in postman.

Comment: okay, I'll try!!

Comment: Hi @debug_dk, I did call the api in postman but got the same error